# @Qualifier not working in spring 5.0.6

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection, annotations, autowired

@Qualifier("id") is now working. It is showing

> No qualifying bean of type 'beans.Engine_AutoAnno' available: expected
>   single matching bean but found 2: e,e1

This is my Engine_AutoAnno.java

```
package beans;
public class Engine_AutoAnno {

    private String model;

    public void setModel(String model) {
        this.model = model;
    }
    public String getModel() {
        return model;
    }
}
```

This is my Car_AutoAnno.java

```
package beans;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;

public class Car_AutoAnno {

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("e")
    private Engine_AutoAnno engine;

    public void printCar() {

        System.out.println("Car engine: "+engine.getModel());
    }
}
```

This is my main class Client_autoAnno.java

```
package testMain;

import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;

import beans.Car_AutoAnno;

public class Client_autoAnno {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        ApplicationContext app = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("resource/spring_autowireAnno.xml");

        Car_AutoAnno car = (Car_AutoAnno) app.getBean("c");

        car.printCar();

    }
}
```

This is my XML file:

```
<!DOCTYPE beans PUBLIC "-//SPRING//DTD BEAN 2.0//EN" "http://www.springframework.org/dtd/spring-beans-2.0.dtd">

<beans>

    <!-- activate autowire annotation -->
    <bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor"/>

    <bean id="c" class="beans.Car_AutoAnno"/>

    <bean id="e" class="beans.Engine_AutoAnno">
        <property name="model" value="XF"/>
    </bean>
    <bean id="e1" class="beans.Engine_AutoAnno">
        <property name="model" value="XJ"/>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

This is the exception i am getting:

> Exception in thread "main"
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:
>   Error creating bean with name 'c': Unsatisfied dependency expressed
>   through field 'engine'; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException: No
>   qualifying bean of type 'beans.Engine_AutoAnno' available: expected
>   single matching bean but found 2: e,e1

How to solve this?

Thanks in avdance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `<context:annotation-config />` in your xml @Qualifier annotations need this.

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context" xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-3.2.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd">
<context:annotation-config />
// your bean definations here.
```

Comment: This is the output when I put that in my XAM file:

`Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionStoreException: Line 6 in XML document from class path resource [resource/spring_autowireAnno.xml] is invalid; nested exception is org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 6; columnNumber: 31; Element type "context:annotation-config" must be declared`

Comment: the namespace in which <annotation-config> exists is not present in your XML. updating my answer with correct namespace

Comment: that worked...thanks again...
I had to add     
spring-aop-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar


I am updating the new XML file as answer now...

Answer (score 1):

The answer given by Mr. [Raghvendra Garg](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1800319/raghvendra-garg)

worked fine...

This is the updated XML file..

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">


    <!-- activate autowire annotation -->
    <context:annotation-config />
    <bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor"/>

    <bean id="c" class="beans.Car_AutoAnno"/>

    <bean id="e" class="beans.Engine_AutoAnno">
        <property name="model" value="XF"/>
    </bean>
    <bean id="e1" class="beans.Engine_AutoAnno">
        <property name="model" value="XJ"/>
    </bean>
</beans>
```